# Would merging openmp regions give a performance benefit?

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp

I have a parallel code which is purely MPI. MPI scales pretty well within 8 cores. However, due to memory requirement I would have to use hybrid code.  My code has following structure

```
for( A Sequential loop for 10e5 iterations)
{
    highly_parallelizable_function_call_1()
    some_sequential_work
    highly_parallelizable_function_call_2()
    some_sequential_work
    MPI_send() 
    MPI_recv() 
    highly_parallelizable_function_call_3()
    highly_parallelizable_function_call_4()    

}
```

roughly function 3 and 4 accounts for 90% of the time. I changed function 3 and 4 to openmp parallel code. And profiling shows I get only speed up of 4-5 on this. Hence this code might not scale as good as MPI alone code. This I suspect can be due to threading overhead. To circumvent this  I would like to change this code to to create thread only at the beginning, as follows

```
#pragma omp parallel
for( A Sequential loop for 10e5 iterations)
{
    parallel_version_function_call_1()

    if( thread_id==0) some_sequential_work 

    parallel_version_function_call_2()

    if( thread_id==0) some_sequential_work 
    if( thread_id==0) MPI_send() 
    if( thread_id==0) MPI_recv()

    parallel_version_function_call_3()
    parallel_version_function_call_4()    

}
```

Would doing something like this be beneficial ?

Comment: It is in progress. It is a very huge code ~4000 lines. For now I'm  writing parallel versions of function call (and wrapping around a local omp parallel pragma)

Answer (score 1):

I think that your current implementation does not pay attention to Amdahl's law (google it if you like). Given that you only parallelized 90% of your code the best possible speedup that you can ask for (given 8 cores) is:

```
Speedup =  1.0 / (p_{seq} + (1 - p_{parallel}) / #cores)
```

Which in your case is:

```
Speedup = 1.0 / ( 0.1 + 0.9 / 8) = 4.71
```

So your current openmp parallelization is doing exactly what would be expected.
Long answer short: Yes, the later implementation should give you a better speedup if this would mean that function 1 and two would be parallelized as well.

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, when I say I only get speed up of 4-5, that is about individual speed up not overall speed up.